# Does Fortran have a standard library?

Tags: fortran

Is there a Fortran standard library (I keep hearing about something called ISO_C_BINDING, but I haven't seen anything documentation for it), and if so where is the documentation (something like http://docs.python.org/ or https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/ would be helpful) ?

Comment: Have you attempted to perform your own research?

Comment: You can learn about the ISO C Binding in the "Mixed-Languages Programming" Chapter of the gfortran manual, in previous answers here, and elsewhere on the WWW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fortran standard specifies a set of "intrinsic" subroutines, which I suppose are akin to the C standard library. It's quite limited in scope, though.

Many Fortran compilers also support intrinsics beyond the ones specified by the standard. For a list of the supported intrinsics, see your compiler manual, such as [Chapter 8 in the GFortran manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Intrinsic-Procedures.html).